# 2 vacuum pumps in parallel

Tags: experimental-physics, vacuum

I have a problem with a vacuum pump that cannot generate enough vacuum to grip an uneven item. There is a spare vacuum pump in parallel which I will turn on and run at the same time to try and get extra vacuum, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your brief description, it sounds like you are operating a vacuum chuck. What kind of pumps are these? A very basic diaphragm or rotary vane pump will easily reach an ultimate vacuum of 100mbar or much lower. Since you are using the pump to hold an item, you probably do not need high vacuum or high pumping speed, because the atmospheric pressure outside the item (14 psi) is being used to hold the object.

Unless your first pump is defective, adding a second identical pump will probably only increase the pumping speed. That is to say, you cannot get "extra vacuum" with the second pump if there are no leaks. I would be careful to check for leaks or to see if your first pump is defective. If there is a leak, the second pump may add enough pumping speed to overcome the leak, but this is not as ideal as a well sealed system.